# Erro ao tentar conectar com o mysql

Tags: mysql, java-ee

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com Java Web e Mysql e quando fui criar a conexão e testar esta dando bastante erro, preciso de ajuda para resolver isso...

```
package br.com.farmacia.factory;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexao {
    private static final String USUARIO = "root";
    private static final String SENHA = "admin";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cafeteria?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

    public static Connection conectar() throws SQLException {
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA);
        return conexao;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conexao = Conexao.conectar();
            System.out.println("Conectado com Sucesso !!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Conexão falhou !!");
        }
    }
}
```

Erros que estão acontecendo

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
>   Conexão falhou !!
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>     at br.com.farmacia.factory.Conexao.conectar(Conexao.java:13)
>     at br.com.farmacia.factory.Conexao.main(Conexao.java:19)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1936)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1865)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
>     ... 14 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolução do problema:
Troquei o mysql-installer-community-8.0.15.0 pelo mysql-installer-community-5.7.22.1 e troquei o mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar pelo mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin e está tudo funcionando 100%

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser algo relacionado a versão o mysqlconnector que você está usando não ser a correta para a versão do mysql instalada. Este post (em inglês) explica exatamente o que te falei.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382824/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-could-not-create-connection-to-database-ser/50383070